# How to check if postgresql crashes and restarts?

Tags: postgresql

I am investigating an error with an application that I think is related to the database restarting and crashing periodically, perhaps it's running out of memory. How do I check to see if a postgresql database is crashing and restarting? IS there a query that I can run?

FWIW, the database is an AWS managed RDS postgresql database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to look for those kinds of errors would be in the logs.  However, if you just want to see when the database last started, you could use this query:

```
SELECT pg_postmaster_start_time();
```

Comment: If you're just looking to find where the database started up, you can look for the phrase it shows when it's ready: `database system is ready to accept connections`